# Better way to handle graphics matrices (instead of the Matrix class)

Tags: c#, matrix, .net-2.0, gdi+, transform

I'm creating a 2D drawing framework for .NET 2.0/GDI+.

I need to be able to define transformations for different visuals, such as rotate and translate transforms.  I also need to be able to transform point coordinates from ancestors to children based on those transformations.

So I have functions like the following:

```
public Matrix TransformToAncestor(Element ancestor)
public Matrix TransformToDescendant(Element descendant)
public PointF TransformPoint(Matrix matrix, PointF point)
```

I rely on the matrix class to perform the following functions:

Multiply, Invert, TransformPoints, RotateAt, Scale

My problem is that the Matrix class is IDisposable and not convenient to use.  I need to be able to create matrices on the fly.  I need to be able to say, "give me a matrix to translate from this element to that element, and use that matrix to transform this point".

The Matrix class allocates unmanaged resources using GDI+ native interop.  So if I don't dispose it as soon as I no longer need it I could be creating a memory leak.

Now as far as I know the Matrix class simply represents an array of 6 elements and it has functions to perform mathematical operations on those elements.  That seems overkill to be making interop calls for.

I really just need a lightweight class which stores those 6 values and has code to manipulate them.  I'm not comfortable enough with matrix math to write all of the code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do: look at WPF's `System.Windows.Media.Matrix` struct ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.aspx ). Either use it directly, or recreate it in your own code (use of ILSpy or Reflector is very helpful here). That way you don't have to be comfortable with the math, you just have to recreate what they're doing (and it gives you a very easy way to unit test, just compare your output to WPF's!).

Then, build up whatever utility, extension, and conversion methods that help you interoperate with GDI+ in a manner that's natural for your library.